# The variance between a teacher's and students' English levels

Tags: teaching

A question to people knowledgeable about teaching in classes: *What is an adequate gap between a teacher's and students' English levels so the students can, actually, learn English?*
For instance, can a certified C1 English user teach B2 students (after passing TKT, CELTA, etc., sure)? What about the same situation on Independent (B2 teaches B1) level? 
In other words, when does it occur when a teacher cannot share his knowledge with others when the difference in the teacher's and students' levels is so slight?

Comment: I'd say it's *never* ideal to be taught a foreign language by someone who isn't a native speaker of that language (or at least, *exceptionally* fluent). I certainly wouldn't want to be taught *anything* by someone who was only a few chapters ahead of me in the study material.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [academia.se].

Comment: Thank you! I do not know appropriate tags to use as I am a newbie, so feel free to move it to the right topic :)